# Adding images to worksheets that obey sorting and filtering rules

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

**Edit**: This is probably a general Excel issue, I'm tracking that here: https://superuser.com/questions/1457518/adding-images-to-excel-that-obey-both-filtering-and-sorting-rules

I am generating worksheets where some rows will have an image embedded with them. Depending on how I embed the image, the images do not hide when the rest of their row's data is hidden OR the images do not sort when the worksheet is sorted.

Example application demonstrating this issue: https://github.com/dan-kirberger/poi-excel-image-issue - it generates two worksheets. Each demonstrating one of my issues. There is also an `examples` folder with pre-generated worksheets if you would prefer to just look at the resulting workbooks.

The worksheet looks like this before any sorting/filtering is applied:

[image]

Sorting/filtering are enabled on the worksheet via:

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(sheet.getFirstRowNum(), sheet.getLastRowNum(), 0, 2));
```

The code (also in the above github link) that adds the image:

```
        Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();
        anchor.setAnchorType(imageAnchorType);
        anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
        anchor.setRow1(cell.getRowIndex());
        Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureId);
        picture.resize(1, 1);
```

In that snippet, `imageAnchorType` is the deciding factor, if set to `MOVE_AND_RESIZE`, the images do not get sorted when using the sort functionality in the filters:
[image]

Notice that the images no longer match the "Text" column. (The image with a picture of "1" is now next to the text of "Two")

If `imageAnchorType` is set to `MOVE_DONT_RESIZE` the images sort appropriately, but when applying filters that remove image rows, the images remain:
[image]

We applied a filter to show "Text only" columns, so the "One" and "Three" row data is gone, but their images remain.

Are there any other properties I should be setting to get this to work the way I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not only the anchor type. To provide both, sorting as well as filtering, `ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE` is correct. For sorting moving must be possible and for filtering resizing must be possible (row height of not visible rows is 0).

But to support sorting, the pictures also must fit into the cells which are sorted. They must not jut out the cells size, because else they will not be sorted together with the cells. So `picture.resize` is not possible because the resizing resizes the picture to it's native size which probably will be bigger than the cell size of the cell the picture is anchored to.

[ClientAnchor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ClientAnchor.html) provides following settings:

`setCol1` which is the first column the anchor is anchored on. The picture's top left edge starts on left edge of that column.

`setDx1` which is the value added to left edge of first column the anchor is anchored on. It shifts the picture horizontally away from left edge of first column.

`setRow1` which is the first row the anchor is anchored on. The picture's top left edge starts on top edge of that row.

`setDy1` which is the value added to top edge of first row the anchor is anchored on. It shifts the picture vertically away from top edge of first row.

`setCol2` which is the second column the anchor is anchored on. The picture's bottom right edge ends on left edge of that column.

`setDx2` which is the value added to left edge of second column the anchor is anchored on. It shifts  bottom right edge of the picture horizontally away from left edge of second column. This will widen the picture horizontally.

`setRow2` which is the second row the anchor is anchored on. The picture's bottom right edge ends on top edge of that row.

`setDy1` which is the value added to top edge of second row the anchor is anchored on. It shifts bottom right edge of the picture vertically away from top edge of second row. This will stretch the picture vertically.

To support sorting, `Row1` and `Row2` must be the same row. So that while sorting that row, the picture belongs to that row. This means the pictures height only can be determined by `Dy2`. And the pictures height must fit into the row height.

Following code shows an example. The pictures I have downloaded from your github.

Code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreateExcelPictures {

 static String excelPath = "ExcelWithPictures.xlsx";
 static String[][] data = new String[][]{
  new String[]{"Image", "Text", "Type"},
  new String[]{"", "One", "One and Three"},
  new String[]{"", "Two", "Two only"},
  new String[]{"", "Three", "One and Three"}
 };
 static String[] pictureFileNames = new String[]{"one.png", "two.png", "three.png"};
 static int pictureWidthPx = 30;
 static int pictureHeightPx = 25;
 static XSSFWorkbook workbook;
 static XSSFSheet sheet;

 static void addImage(int col1, int row1, int col2, int row2, 
  int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2,
  String imageFileName, ClientAnchor.AnchorType anchorType) throws Exception {

  InputStream imageInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFileName);
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(imageInputStream);
  int pictureId = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
  imageInputStream .close();

  XSSFClientAnchor anchor = workbook.getCreationHelper().createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setAnchorType(anchorType);
  // set Col1, Dx1, Row1, Dy1, Col2, Dx2, Row2, Dy2
  // only this determines the picture's size then
  anchor.setCol1(col1);
  anchor.setDx1(dx1);
  anchor.setRow1(row1);
  anchor.setDy1(dy1);
  anchor.setCol2(col2);
  anchor.setDx2(dx2);
  anchor.setRow2(row2);
  anchor.setDy2(dy2);

  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  XSSFPicture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureId);

 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  int r = 0;
  for (String[] rowData : data) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
   int c = 0;
   for (String cellData : rowData) {
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c++);
    cell.setCellValue(cellData);
   }
   if (r > 0) {
    float rowHeight = (float)Units.pixelToPoints(pictureHeightPx); // picture's height must fit into row height
    row.setHeightInPoints(rowHeight);
    addImage(0, r, 0, r, /*all fits in one cell*/
     /*Dx1 = 0 and Dy1 = 0, picture's top left edge starts on top left of the cell*/
     Units.pixelToEMU(0), Units.pixelToEMU(0), 
     /*Dx2 is picture's width and Dy2 is picture's height, picture's bottom right edge ends on that point into the cell*/
     Units.pixelToEMU(pictureWidthPx), Units.pixelToEMU(pictureHeightPx),
     pictureFileNames[r-1], ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
   }
   r++; 
  }

  sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 15*256);
  sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0, 3, 0, 2));

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelPath);
  workbook.write(fos);
  fos.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Sorting as well as filtering are possible.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much! I stopped resizing the picture and instead specified the coordinates/size the way you described.

I'm left with one headache - the fact that row heights don't travel with the row when sorting (which appears to be Excel behavior) so I have all of my rows set to a fixed height (enough to accommodate the thumbnails being embedded in them)